# Can't figure out adding/removing classes with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wordpress

I need help with this JS code for my wordpress theme.
First part is when it looks for h4 heading and if it has certain text it wraps all paragraphs below this h4 into div (which hides all paragraphs into fading section) and adds "button" (which is span):

```
var tutustu = 'TUTUSTU'; 
    var syvenny = 'SYVENNY';

    $('.article_content h4').each(function(){
        if($(this).text() == tutustu)
        {
            $(this).nextUntil("h4").wrapAll('<div class="expand" />').parent().append('<span id="expand">show more</span>');
        }
        else if($(this).text() == syvenny) {
            $(this).nextUntil("h4").wrapAll('<div class="expand" />').parent().append('<span id="expand">show more</span>');
        }
    });
```

Second is when user clicks on "button" div (that we wrapped into all paragraphs early) will get another class (to basicaly reveal all the paragraphs) and remover button:

```
$('span#expand').click(function() {
  $(this).parent('.expand').removeClass('expand').addClass('expanded');
  $(this).remove();
});
```

What I need is after paragraph text is revealed I want to have button to click on and everything goes back like in 1st part.
I came up with something like this:

```
$('span#expanded').click(function() {
  $(this).parent('.expanded').removeClass('expanded').addClass('expand');
});
```

But it doesn't work (
Help is much appreciated

Comment: Check $(this).parent('.expand').length

Comment: you might want to change to `$(this).parents('.expanded')`.. parent will only get the direct parent of an item, whereas parents will get matching elements you provide in selector, regardless of heirarchy level.

Comment: I think toggleClass not gonna work in this case because trigger (the button) changes its ID and content ("shoew more/show less)

Comment: @SergeyDubovik: if you have found the solution to answer then lets close this question by ticking over the `ANSWER` posted below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `event Delegation` and `.toggleClass()` instead of `.addClass()` and `.removeClass()`

```
$(document).on("click" , "span#expanded" , function() {
  $(this).parent().toggleClass('expanded expand');
});
```

Comment: This code breakes js on page unfortunately. Console says SyntaxError: Unexpected token (

Answer (score 1):

```
 $('#expanded').on('click', function(e) {
   $(this).parent().toggleClass('expanded expand');
   e.preventDefault();
  });
```

Comment: same as above code breakes js on page unfortunately. Console says SyntaxError: Unexpected token ( –